# Mongoose validation failed: Path is required

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

It's weird for Mongoose to say that because I'm pretty sure I have the thing.

This is my Mongoose model:

```
var Job = mongoose.model('Job', new Schema({
_creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
companyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
position: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
isCurrent: {
    type: Boolean
    // required: true
},
startedDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
endDate: {
    type: Date
},
descriptions: [{
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    skills: [{
        skillId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        },
        skillName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }]

}]
}));
```

And here's the dummy data I'm trying to send to my server, printed right before posting:
[image]

Yet it tells me that it requires the path `description` which is already included in the job object above:

[image]

Super confused. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you still get that error when you provide `skillId` & `skillName`?

Comment: @Akrion Thanks for replying & good question. That's another thing I'm trying to find out. But I guess mongo just stopped the process once it can't find description so it's not showing.

Comment: Can you share the code of the controller which saves the data to db?